# Slider animation handle with JQuery, hover element issue using promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, promise

I have problem with a slider. It works correctly without one, strange for me, situation. When I mouseover fast from one dot to another, it will not wait until previous animation ends and two texts overlap. Can somebody older and wiser help me?

HTML structure of project:

```
<section class="product-section">
<div class="vertical-text vertical-text-custom-5">
    Pluginy
</div>
<div class="carrousel-image-container-1 product-release-management">
    <i class="image-carrousel-1"></i>
</div>
<div class="carrousel-image-container-2 product-SLA">
    <i class="image-carrousel-2"></i>
</div>
<div class="carrousel-image-container-3 product-test-management">
    <i class="image-carrousel-3"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-custom-5">
    <div class="col-custom-7 text-size-xl">
        <div class="text-container-17">
            <div class="product product-release-management">
                <span class="text-color-6 text-weight-thin">Rivet</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-5 text-weight-bold">Release Management</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-3 text-weight-bold">plugin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="product product-SLA">
                <span class="text-color-6 text-weight-thin">Rivet</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-5 text-weight-bold">SLA</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-3 text-weight-bold">plugin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="product product-test-management">
                <span class="text-color-6 text-weight-thin">Rivet</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-5 text-weight-bold">Test Management</span> <br>
                <span class="text-color-3 text-weight-bold">plugin</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carrousel-dots-contener" class="carrousel-dots text-color-5">
            <div class="dot-container" data-carrousel-dot='dot-1'>
                <div class="dot-border">
                    <div class="dot dot-custom-2">&#9679;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--
                 -->
            <div class="dot-container" data-carrousel-dot='dot-2'>
                <div class="dot-border">
                    <div class="dot dot-custom-2">&#9679;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--
                 -->
            <div class="dot-container" data-carrousel-dot='dot-3'>
                <div class="dot-border">
                    <div class="dot dot-custom-2">&#9679;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[REST OF CODE HERE](http://jsbin.com/mocezuwema/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the main issues:

- The `promise()` call works fine when you are sure you don't need to interrupt the animation, but as soon as you have mouse events that need immediate action (like *hideAll*), this promise will become a problem: it will still resolve, but at an inconvenient moment. In fact, as soon as you do another animation like *hideAll*, you want to cancel the execution of the code that follows the resolved promise. So... add a condition before proceeding with `fadeIn()` to see that the product selection is still relevant.
- *runInterval* calls *cyclicChange* immediately, which is great when the page loads, but which is a bit annoying when moving the mouse over one dot to the next: as the mouse may exit the area, *runInterval* gets called and makes the selection jump to potentially another dot, which makes it kinda jumpy. It is better to remove this immediate call to *cyclicChange* and then to add some code to show the first product when *start* runs.
- To avoid unwanted queuing of animations, you could call `stop(true)` before doing `fadeOut()`.

I applied these changes to your JavaScript code, where I also made some other improvements, unrelated to the problem:

```
var carrousel = (function() {

    var interval = null,
        products,
        current = -1;

    products = [
        '.product-release-management',
        '.product-SLA',
        '.product-test-management'
    ];

    function showProduct(id) {
        // Avoid unnecessary work
        if (id == current) return; // nothing to do;
        // In other cases: hide first
        hideAll();
        current = id;
        $('.product').promise().done(function() {
            // Make sure selection is still like at the start of showProduct execution
            if (current === id) $(products[current]).fadeIn(500);
        });
        $("div[data-carrousel-dot='dot-" + (current + 1) + "']").addClass('dot-active');
    }        
    function hideAll() {
        // 1. easier selector for selecting all product classes
        // 2. stop any ongoing animation
        $(products.join(",")).stop(true, true).fadeOut(500); 
        $("div[data-carrousel-dot").removeClass('dot-active');
    }
    function cyclicChange() {
        if ( isNaN(interval) ) return; // timer is not active
        showProduct((current + 1) % products.length); // easier way to roundtrip
    }
    function runInterval(){
        interval = setInterval(cyclicChange, 3000); 
    }
    function mouseOverDotHandler() {
        $('.dot-container').hover(    
            function() {
                // Easier way to get number
                showProduct($(this).index());
            }
        );

        $('#carrousel-dots-contener').hover(
            function(){
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null; // use variable for indicating the pause
            },
            runInterval
        );
    }

    return {
        start: function() {
            showProduct(0);
            runInterval();
            mouseOverDotHandler();
        }
    }
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    carrousel.start();
});
```

See it run on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/nifoguweve/1/edit?html,css,js,output).